# Add a value in a multidimensional vector in a specific position

Tags: c++, vector

I can’t understand how I can add a new element in a multidimensional vector in a particular position. 
My vector is

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> symbols
```

I have two indices i0 and i1 and a char value.
I want to insert value in that specific position, but if I try to do something like :

```
symbols[i0][i1] = value
```

How can I use the insert method? 
My vector has to be dynamic. Its dimensions have to change when I insert a value in a specific position.

Comment: Take a look at [insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/)

Comment: The insert gives problem too, and I don’t know why

Comment: "gives problem" is a really bad problem description. Could you include a [mcve] please?

Comment: I presume you have to properly *initialize* vector first to be able to *insert in a specific position*. Otherwise, you can use `push_back()`.

Comment: I might guess that array is not of a correct size for you to access the elements by these indices. Arrays (and vectors) are contiguous areas of memory, so when accessing index K, you need to have at least K elements in your vector. Otherwise, you can add a new element to the end of array with push_back.

Comment: I can’t use push_back() because I have to insert my element in a specific position.

Comment: @Valeriy Savchenko yes, in fact I change the size of the vector (named symbols) as: symbols.reserve(i0+1)

Comment: I would like to understand how to insert an element in a multidimensional vector in a position described by two indices : i0 and i1 using the insert method.

Comment: Does the structure have to remain rectangular?

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to index into your multi-dimension vector you must already initialize it fully, and that i0 < length of outer vector, and i1 < length of inner vector.  Assuming all inner vectors are of same size.  Suppose you want a 10x10 vector,

Using C++11:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> symbols(10, std::vector<char>(10));
```

now your vector is initialized as a vector containing 10 vectors each of size 10, at this point you can index into it like the square matrix.

You can use insert by,

```
symbols[i0].insert(symbols[i0].begin() + i1, 'a');
```

What this is doing is first you retrieve the inner vector base on i0, from there you can perform insert at a specific offset from the beginning iterator.  You just have to make sure the index is not beyond the length of the vector.

Comment: My vector has to be completely dynamic and its dimensions have always to change when I want to insert a value. So I can’t choose an initial dimension

Comment: @MartinaPianist96 that's a dubious design.. they are dynamic... but you cant use [] before you create an element.and inserting new "row" is a costy operation, it re-allocates whole vector

Answer (score 1):

**The problem with the vector**

It seems you are trying to use a container for something it has not be designed for:

A vector is a consecutive array of elements, of a specific size. In consequence, you cannot add a value at a given position like:

```
myVector[5] = value; // wrong if myVector.size()<6
```

You would need either to

- Resize the vector: `myVector.resize(6);`
- Push elements sequentially: `for (size_t i=0; i< 6; ++i) myVector.push_back(i);`

**Recomendation**

What you seem to want (and correct me if I am wrong), is to be able to add a value at any place, without setting the size, neither having to fill all the holes.

For this purpose, what I would recommend, is the `unordered_map` which has very good properties:

- constant access
- usually constant insertion (when a resize is not required)

An `unordered_map` is a `hash table` with a key and a value. In your case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    using UnlimitedTable = unordered_map<size_t,unordered_map<size_t, char>>;

    UnlimitedTable table;

    table[3][5] = 'A';
    table[1][2] = 'B';

    cout << table[3][5] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want o know more about what Adrian is recommending, look up the search term "Sparse Matrix".

Answer (score 0):

To stay with what you asked, I understand that you need something like a matrix, but with rows and columns that dynamically grow as you insert elements. For inserting you can use what noobius suggested:

```
symbols[i0].insert(symbols[i0].begin() + i1, 'a');
```

You need, as suggested by Adrian Maire, to pay attention that i0 is a valid index, so

```
i0<symbols.capacity().
```

I think you can try with something like this:

```cc
template <typename T>
void Myinsert(std::vector<std::vector<T >>& symbols, int* index, const T& toInsert){
    int i0=index[0];
    int i1=index[1];
    float mul_fct=1.5; //just to avoid too many reallocations

    if(i0>=symbols.capacity())
        symbols.resize(i0*mul_fct);
    if(i1>=symbols[i0].capacity())
        symbols[i0].resize(i1*mul_fct);


    symbols[i0].insert(symbols[i0].begin()+i1, toInsert);
}
```

This function perform the insert() but also checks that i0 and i1 are correct indexes and make the vector reallocate itself if they are not.
Just to test the program you can have a main.cpp like this:

```
    std::vector<std::vector<wchar_t >> symbols(1);
    int index1[]={0,1}, index2[]={0,2}, index3[]={24,7};

    //insertion1
    Myinsert(symbols, index1, L'a');
    print_vec(symbols);

    //insertion2
    Myinsert(symbols, index2, L'b');
    print_vec(symbols);

    //insertion3
    Myinsert(symbols, index3, L'c');
    print_vec(symbols);

    //insertion4
    Myinsert(symbols, index3, L'z');
    print_vec(symbols);
```